# is there way to display the entire list of elements in a combo-box(input text box and datalist)?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

i'm developing this feature in my angular application..

Example: i have list of ice-cream flavours as in the below code

```
<label for="ice-cream-choice">Choose a flavor:</label>
<input list="ice-cream-flavors" id="ice-cream-choice" name="ice-cream-choice" />

<datalist id="ice-cream-flavors">
    <option value="Chocolate">
    <option value="Coconut">
    <option value="Mint">
    <option value="Strawberry">
    <option value="Vanilla">
</datalist>
```

below is the output i get,

[image]

once i select any of the options from the below list, it only displays the selected in the dropdown. as below
[image]

my requirement is to display the entire list even i select one of them, i would like to see the other options? as below

[image]

let me know if you need any additional info...

Comment: No, the browser automatically filters the entries to show only those, that match the input the user made so far. There is no option or attribute to change this behavior. If you don't want it, then you can't to use datalist to begin with, but need to implement a custom solution.

Comment: @CBroe: Thanks for your prompt reply, i understand what your saying , any hints to develop this custom solution?

Comment: You can probably take some inspiration from any of the countless number of "autocomplete" scripts that can be found on the net.

Comment: use a regular select input field instead.